# I'm trying to create a simple progressbar in html, css. But the my divs are overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a parent and a child div. And I want to place the parent's text over child's background color. Check out my example, so it makes more sense. I would like to achive this look: [goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akfYM.jpg)

Right now I'm using opacity to not cover the progress bar's label. My goal is to just use normal colors without opacity and still see the label clearly.

```
 <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner"></div>
      67 / 90
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjr40oqt/5/

Comment: Your problem is that the inner `div` element will always cover the inner text node. See my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
div.outer {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    height: 1em;
}

div.inner {
    height: 26px;
    background-color: green;
    width: calc((67 / 90) * 100%);
    position: absolute;
}

div.label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="label">67 / 90</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow: hidden;` on your outer div to avoid the overflow of inner div

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My problem is that I still have to use opacity on the inner div's color. If I use normal color, it just covers my data label. :(

Comment: Yea you need to use position: absolute along with z-index on the data label t bring it on top of the div. I think ZorgoZ's answer does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

how about just moving the .inner in the background using

```
z-index: -1;
```

result: https://jsfiddle.net/wmt056dn/